# Proof x^n/n! is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I came across this question in my math workbook, but wasn't able to solve it.

Prove that the sequence $a_n = \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is bounded.

This is my definition of bounded: $\exists M>0 \hspace{-1mm}: \hspace{5mm} |a_n|<M \hspace{5mm} \forall n\in\mathbb{N} $.

UPDATE: I am aware I could prove convergence and then prove all convergent sequences are bounded, but I assumed there exists a direct method to prove boundedness using the definition (Hence this question was not meant as a duplicate).

Comment: If you weren't able to solve it, what did you try?

Comment: I proved convergence, then I proved all convergent sequences are bounded. Because of the terminology in my book, I assume there is a direct method to prove boundedness. I have no clue how to continue from the definition given above. Have been searching for similar examples, but haven't found them. It is possible to prove boundedness direct, right?

Answer (score 0):

The hint.

We have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{x}{n+1}\rightarrow0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ be for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the function
$$
a_n\left(x\right)=\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
Hence for $x \ne 0$
$$
\left|\frac{a_{n+1}\left(x\right)}{a_n\left(x\right)}\right| \leq \frac{\left|x\right|^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)n!}\frac{n!}{\left|x\right|}=\frac{\left|x\right|}{n+1}\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$
Hence the series $\sum_{n \geq 0}^{ }a_n(x)$ converges for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence
$$
a_n(x)\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$
Hence, $a_n(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is bounded because it converges.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different

$\frac {x^n}{n!} = \prod \frac x1\frac x2 ....... \frac x{n}$.

Let $n > |x|$.  Then $a_(n+1) = \frac {x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = (\prod \frac x1\frac x2 ....... \frac x{n})\frac x{n+1} < a_n$

So  $a_n \le \max \{a_m\}_{m \le |x|}$.